# How to calculate X.509 certificate's SHA-1 fingerprint?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, x509

I'm trying to implement an X.509 certificate generator from scratch (I know about the existing ones, but I need yet another one). What I cannot understand is how to calculate the SHA-1 (or any other) fingerprint of the certificate.

The [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.1.3) says that the input to the signature function is the DER-encoded tbsCertificate field. Unfortunately, the hash that I calculate differs from the one produced by OpenSSL. Here's a step-by-step example.

1. Generate a certificate using OpenSSL's x509 tool (in a binary DER form, *not* the ASCII PEM)
2. Calculate its SHA-1 hash using `openssl x509 -fingerprint`
3. Extract the TBS field using `dd` (or anything else) and store it in a separate file; calculate its hash using the `sha1sum` utility

Now, the hashes I get at steps 2 and 3 are different. Can someone please give me a hint what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: When you calculate the SHA-1 hash of the tbsCertificate, are you using [PKCS#1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2313) padding, as specified in [rfc 3279](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3279)?

Comment: Uhm... RFC2313 (PKCS#1) only specifies RSA encryption. As far as I understand, padding is not needed at the SHA-1 computing phase?

Comment: Oh, by the way, at the Step 3 I calculate the hash using sha1sum utility

Comment: Arrrgh, my bad! Actually, `openssl x509 -fingerprint` simply outputs SHA-1 hash of the WHOLE DER-encoded certificate (not only the tbsCertificate part)

Comment: @Roman D: Since it's not at all obvious, you should write that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @caf: thank you for reminding me to do it! Done :)

Comment: But how is it possible to get the hash over the whole certificate, isn't that a chicken and egg problem. I mean how can we calculate hash over the whole certificate ( tbsCertificate TBSCertificate, signatureAlgorithm AlgorithmIdentifier, signatureValue BIT STRING ) without having the signature value. or you mean just its just over TBSCertificate along with the header on top of TBSCertificate

Comment: Nope. If we are talking about the fingerprint as reported by the OpenSSL (`openssl x509 -fingerprint`), it is actually a mere SHA1 hash of the whole certificate. It is not stored in the certificate itself. Compare the output of the `openssl x509 -fingerprint -inform der -in YOUR_CERT.DER` and the `sha1sum YOUR_CERT.DER`. Be careful to use the DER-encoded certificate for this experiment, NOT the PEM one!

Comment: Hi, I have a doubt here. If the hash is calculated over the whole certificate, then how come all the certificates in the Certification Path have different "Thumbprint" ? One more doubt, is the sha-1 fingerprint and thumbprint of a certificate the same thing?

Comment: @Abhineet, how do you get the thumbprint of the certificate? I'm not sure what it is. You can calculate SHA-1 of the certificate and see if it the same as thumbprint or not.

Comment: OK..let me make myself more clear. Right click any signed PE and view all the certificates. They all have a unique thumbprint with them. So, what i am asking is, Do you know any way to calculate that Thumbprint? I have tried calculating the certificate sha-1 but no use and then again I tried calculating the sha-1 of public key with and without exponent but again no progress. Can you guide me how to do that or how to make the certification path as they show in the properties of a signed PE?

Comment: @Abhineet, I don't have a Windows PC available right now to take a look. Maybe the thumbprint that is shown there is the hash of the public key, as described in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate)?

Comment: Yeah even I went through that and tried but to no positive conclusion. Anyways thanks for the help @RomanD

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok, so it turned out that the fingerprint calculated by OpenSSL is simply a hash over the **whole** certificate (in its DER binary encoding, **not** the ASCII PEM one!), not only the TBS part, as I thought.

For anyone who cares about calculating certificate's digest, it is done in a different way: the hash is calculated over the DER-encoded (again, *not* the PEM string) TBS part *only*, including its ASN.1 header (the ID 0x30 == ASN1_SEQUENCE | ASN1_CONSTRUCTED and the length field). Please note that the certificate's ASN.1 header is not taken into account.

Comment: you could add to your answer (or question) how you extracted the TBS part with dd exactly for future reference :)

Comment: Oh... That was quite a while ago, so I don't remember the details. I think I manually extracted the TBS offset and length from the hexdump of the certificate, and then used these values as dd's arguments, nothing complicated there

Comment: @Roman D your answer says 'hash over the whole certificate' in the first paragraph and 'TBS part only' in the second paragraph. Is this a mistake? And what is the TBS part of a certificate? I couldn't find anything useful from my google search.

Comment: @chitti No, it is not a mistake, I even put it in italics to stress the idea. :) First paragraph is about the fingerprint, second one is about the digest. You can read about the TBSCertificate field in the RFC5280 (see 4.1.1, 4.1.1.1, 4.1.2). Basically, it is one of the required fields of a certificate (other two are signatureAlgorithm and signatureValue).

Comment: @FilipePina You can use the OpenSSL function i2d_X509_CINF to get the TBS portion of the X509.

Answer (score 3):

The finger print is similar to term "Thumbprint" in .net. Below code snippet should help you to compute finger print :

```
    public String generateFingerPrint(X509Certificate cert) throws CertificateEncodingException,NoSuchAlgorithmException {

MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(cert.getEncoded[]);

final char delimiter = ':';
// Calculate the number of characters in our fingerprint
      // ('# of bytes' * 2) chars + ('# of bytes' - 1) chars for delimiters
      final int len = hash.length * 2 + hash.length - 1;
      // Typically SHA-1 algorithm produces 20 bytes, i.e. len should be 59
      StringBuilder fingerprint = new StringBuilder(len);

      for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
         // Step 1: unsigned byte
         hash[i] &= 0xff;

         // Steps 2 & 3: byte to hex in two chars
         // Lower cased 'x' at '%02x' enforces lower cased char for hex value!
         fingerprint.append(String.format("%02x", hash[i]));

         // Step 4: put delimiter
         if (i < hash.length - 1) {
            fingerprint.append(delimiter);
         }
      }

      return fingerprint.toString();


    }
```

Comment: This is not .NET.  Looks like Java.

Comment: @JSON please feel free to come up something similar with .NET