# How to get the thumbprint of a X509Certificate certificate?

Tags: c#, x509certificate

To validate in the client the certificate that it receives from the server, the validation method has a parameter of type X509Certificate that is the server certificate.

When I debug, I can see that it has a Thumbprint property, but when I try to access to them in the way myCertificate.Thmbprint I get a compiler error that it says that the property doesn't exist.

However, the type X509Certificate2 has this property.

So how could I get the thmbprint to know if it is the expected certificate?

Thanks.

Comment: Does [How to calculate X.509 certificate's SHA-1 fingerprint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803799/how-to-calculate-x-509-certificates-sha-1-fingerprint) help? Or are you looking for the [X509Certificate.GetCertHashString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getcerthashstring)?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] that provides context? Which "validation method" are you talking about? Do you really mean the `OnCertificateValidated` *event*, which is called *after* the certificate is validated?

Comment: Thumbprint in .NET is the same than Fingerprint. The first link it could help, but it implements a method to calculate it. I would like to know if the type X509Certificate in .NET offers this data directly.

Comment: Are you using (classic) ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core? Which version?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're in a context where you have the cert as `X509Certificate` rather than the more powerful `X509Certificate2`.

Your two easy options:

1. Upcast.  (`X509Certificate2 myCertificate2 = (X509Certificate2)myCertificate;`)
2. Use the `GetCertHash()` or `GetCertHashString()` methods (depending on if you want bytes or the hex string).  `GetCertHashString()` is the same as the `Thumbprint` property.

Comment: The reason I asked for context above is that the `OnCertificateValidated` event receives a context with a `ClientCertificate` property, which is already of type `X509Certificate2` and doesn't need to be cast. But that only matters if that's what OP was talking about and that hasn't been established yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ServicePointManager class to inspect the remote certificate provided and do whatever comparisons you'd like. You can choose to accept or reject it.

[ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback?view=net-7.0)